# Vue.js: inconsistent "Unknown Custom Element" that's resolved on a HMR

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

**I am familiar with component registration. This is not the low-hanging fruit related to:**

- [Vue.js component Unknown custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349092/vue-js-component-unknown-custom-element)
- [Unknown custom element when nesting components in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834201/unknown-custom-element-when-nesting-components-in-vue-js)

### The Problem

When using the dev server I am experiencing an inconsistent "Unknown Custom Element" issue within one component (Now several). This only seems to occur if I reload the page, and will start working correctly if I prompt the dev server to a hot module reload (HMR) (Ie. changing something in the template and saving the file).

- Component: `PropertyEditForm`
- Imported Component: `ViewEditChip`
- `ViewEditChip` *is used in other components without issue*
- I assign the component as expected in `PropertyEditForm`

  - `components: {'view-edit-chip': ViewEditChip}` (ts)
- This issue goes away if I trigger a HMR, but always exists after a reload of the app

**Error:**

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

### Code

*Remember this is TypeScript using class-component syntax*

**`ViewEditChip` declaration:**

```
@Component({name: 'view-edit-chip'})
```

**`PropertyEditForm`declaration:**

```
@Component({
    name: 'property-edit-form',
    components: {
        'view-edit-chip': ViewEditChip
    }
})
```

**`PropertyEditForm`template usage:**

```
<view-edit-chip :item.sync="item"></view-edit-chip>
```

### Thoughts

- I'm unsure if this is related to where it's being used, or how it's being used?
- I doubt this is a problem related to the `ViewEditChip` itself, or it's import as it's used in many other places without problems.

  - In fact, most of the structure of `PropertyEditForm` is copy/pasted from other working components
- Webpack issue?

### Additional Info

This is starting to occur with more and more components in my app. I do not know the cause, and cannot come up with a reproduction case. All of these errors occur only on a full reload of the site, and are fixed on an HMR, and may or may not occur with the same components depending on where in the app they are used, which seems non-sensible to me.

For instance, I have a `FileSystemTree`, `FileSystemToolbar`, & `FileSystemMainView` components. If I use these in a view `FileSystemView` it works as expected. If I create a `FileSystem`, component in the same directory as the above three, so it's reusable, I start getting the error even if it's a copy/paste of the code from `FileSystemView`.

**Example of limited workaround**

If I move `FileSystem` up one directory, and change the imports to the subdir (Has an `index.ts`) instead of `.` the problem vanishes. But if I move it back down to the same directory as the components it's importing, the problem comes back.

Comment: Can you share your projects repo? I have several guesses but it would help a lot to just have a look

Comment: It sounds like you've done your research, but I don't think this can be solved on S/O without providing more code - or all of it - unless a miracle occurs. I'd recommend filing an issue on Vue's github page and including the webpack config (or at least relevant snippets).  Another option is to fork your repo, delete stuff until you have a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then share the entire repo from github or another open source repo.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a codebase I can share :/ I have a feeling this might have to do with webpack or  module import wackiness, both of which I know little about, being a backend dev and all.

Comment: Unless you can provide a minimal reproducible example, it's unlikely this question will get a solid answer, especially since this is a very specific case.

Comment: Hm, I will see what I can do to reproduce this outside of this application. However, I seem to have found some progress with changing `import`s to import files directly vs from a directory (`index.ts`).

Comment: @DouglasGaskell I'll assume you have already fixed it, but I was having the same error in my environment (I'm also using TS with class-component) and, in my case, it turned out to be a circular dependency issue. After the HMR happened, it could resolve the dependencies successfully, but not before then. I had component A using B which used A (a nested editor in a modal). If someone else is having the same error and doesn't know why, check for it.

Comment: @ThiagoSilveira is on the correct path,  circular references where the problem in my case

Comment: @DouglasGaskell, did you solve it?  Was it indeed a circular reference?

Comment: Did you solve it? I've been having this problem for months

Comment: The issue I was running into was importing files from modules in the same dir (index.ts), instead of directly.

Comment: It was a problem of circular references for me too. Drawing the dependency graph on a piece of paper helped.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue appears to happen inconsistently, and your program works as-expected after a hot-reload, but not after refreshing, you may be registering your component after Vue initialization. Here is an example of incorrect and correct global component registration from of the vue-js-modal from main.js.

For example (incorrect):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

import VModal from "vue-js-modal";
Vue.use(VModal)
```

Should be:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VModal from "vue-js-modal";
Vue.use(VModal)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```